# Query returning Fatal error: Cannot use object of type QueryResult as array

Tags: mysql

Hi I am running my own php/mysql application which has its own users table and is imbedded into a joomla site which has its own users table, when i create a new user in my app it creates an associated record in joomla table so i can manage single sign on.  This works fine, however I am now trying to delete the user from the joomla table when I delete from my application, this is code:

```
$rstmp = CustomQuery("select id as id from zzz_users where email='".$deleted_values["Email"]."'"); 
$datatmp = db_fetch_array($rstmp); 
$id = $rstmp["id"]; 

//Delete from joomla tables
$sql2 = "DELETE * FROM zzz_user_usergroup_map WHERE user_id='$id'";  CustomQuery($sql2);
$sql3 = "DELETE * FROM zzz_users WHERE email='".$deleted_values["Email"]."'";  CustomQuery($sql3);
```

But it is returning with the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type QueryResult as array

Help?

Comment: Which line generates this error?

Comment: I'm betting `$rstmp["id"]`. Why don't you use `$datatmp` instead?

Comment: This one $id = $rstmp["id"];

Answer (score 1):

Instead of access to id like `$id = $rstmp["id"];` you should access to it like `$id = $datatmp["id"];` as on the other way you are trying to access to the query result without using fetch

Comment: have updated that but still not playing - cant believe i missed it in first place

Comment: does it remind the same error? In what line do you get the error?

Comment: ok now getting this You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM zzz_user_usergroup_map WHERE user_id='793'

Comment: so it is now getting the id, but apparently my code for deletion has a problem, which is confusing as I use the same code elsewhere (different table) and it works fine

Comment: Try removing * from your queries